# can I remove specific app reference in my development of Shopify theme(unpublish theme)?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I am trying to make one feature in my Shopify theme that is currently integrated using 3rd party app. now I am achieving the same functionality using liquid code and javascript code but now I want to test without the app and once all tested on the development and if all working well then an then I want to push or deploy on a live one.

so for that, I want to remove that 3rd party app reference in the development theme only. the app will add js using a script tag.

I am using Shopify CLI to develop the theme feature. also I have blocked the JS of that app from the console window but I need to block it permanently on an unpublish theme so I can send the preview link to everyone to test the same things on a different machine and in a different browser.

Comment: What kind of functionality is provided by the APP? like add HTML and Javascript events on the website or something else?

Comment: @Onkar app will add script tag so for  me I am blocking this JS but now I want to share my work with colleagues via share link and they got both button one is added by me and one is added from app